# Membros estáticos são coletados pelo GC quando não são mais necessários?

Tags: c#, .net, memória, garbage-collector, variável-estática

Em uma classe que tenha uma variável estática, ela existe por toda a aplicação. O objeto vinculado é coletado em algum momento?

Exemplo:

```
public class Exemplo {
    private static List<int> lista = new List<int>();
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A variável nunca será coletada, ela fica em uma área estática e como você mesmo disse, dura o tempo da aplicação. Então qualquer objeto referenciado por ela se manterá vivo o tempo todo. O objeto estático é uma das raízes de pesquisa do GC, então ele pegará uma referência e mantém o objeto vivo.

Mas obviamente que existe como a variável deixar de referenciar aquela variável. Em algum momento a aplicação pode trocar a referência para outra referência e aí se o objeto anteriormente referenciado não tiver outras referências ele será coletado.

Claro que se anular essa variável também deixa de ter essa referência.

Se ainda existir uma referência para o objeto é possível assiná-la para esse campo estático novamente. Se não tiver mais referências para ele não tem como usar o objeto novamente. A ressurreição só pode ocorrer durante a finalização dele, o que deve ser evitada. Mas isto é outro assunto.

```
public class Exemplo {
    private static List<int> lista = new List<int>();
    public static TrocaLista() {
        lista = new List<int>(); //o objeto anterior ficará sem referência
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura.](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Method/ChangeObjetct.cs)

Na verdade se a variável tiver o atributo [`ThreadStatic`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threadstaticattribute?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-6.0) a própria variável pode ser coletada depois do fim da *thread*.