# Propriedades estáticas e liberação de memória

Tags: c#, testes-de-unidade, selenium-webdriver, garbage-collector, static

Estou com algumas dúvidas em relação a liberação dos recursos para casos onde meus modificadores são estáticos.

Meu projeto é de teste unitário e estou usando Selenium pela primeira vez.

```
public class LoginTest : Base
{
        [ClassInitialize]
        public static void Iniciar(TestContext context) { }

        [TestMethod]
        public void Logar()
        {
            var loginPage = new LoginPage(driverGC);
            loginPage.Navegar("http://localhost:3533/Authorize/LogOn").Logar("usuario@dominio.com.br", "123456");
            Assert.IsTrue(loginPage.VerificarMenuLateral());
        }

        ...
}

public abstract class Base
{
        protected static IWebDriver driverGC = new ChromeDriver(@"C:\chromedriver_win32");
}
```

A propriedade é estática para que todos os testes ocorram com referência ao que já se foi obtido e para não haver novas instâncias do navegador a cada método executado. É uma prática não recomendável?

Acontece que tenho várias classes para teste. Todas herdando de base. Li em vários lugares que objetos, métodos e classes estáticas não são liberadas da memória no processo normal do GC.

Isso quer dizer que para cada primeiro método de teste executado em cada classe, terei uma carga na memória da propriedade `driverGC` que nunca será liberada?

Ou, sendo a propriedade de uma classe que não é estática, ela será removida junto a liberação da classe?

Ou, ainda, esta propriedade virá para a próxima classe com os valores obtidos na execução da classe anterior?

Implementei dentro de cada classe de teste um método:

```
[ClassCleanup]
public static void Finalizar()
{
    driverGC.Close();
    driverGC.Dispose();
}
```

Isso acarretará em liberação de memória após execução?

Vomo faço pra acompanhar todos os objetos carregados em memória em tempo de execução e suas respectivas liberações? Tem como?

Comment: A resposta resolveu o que estava em dúvida? Precisa que algo mais seja melhorado? Acha que é possível aceitá-la agora?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O objeto na variável estática não será liberado porque a memória é estática, não faria sentido liberar isso. Mas o objeto que for referenciado na variável estática pode ser liberado sim, desde que não existam outras referências para ele. Se tiver, não tem porque liberar também.

Então precisa se perguntar se o objeto deve continuar existindo ou não. Se não deve, basta anulá-lo (`null`) na variável estática.

Esse método `Finalizar()` parece uma bela gambiarra. Você pode garantir que em todas situações esse método será chamado? Ele é necessário?

O `Close()` provavelmente deveria estar dentro do `Dispose()`. Esse `Dispose()` é necessário? Ele faz o que? O que eu vi [no código](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/ceaf3da79542024becdda5953059dfbb96fb3a90/dotnet/src/webdriver/Chrome/ChromeDriver.cs) parece que não existe este método. Se existisse, provavelmente teria que ser chamado em algum lugar, mas não parece que tenha um lugar para fazer isso. E provavelmente deveria usar `using`.

O `Iniciar()` também não parece fazer algum sentido.

Membros estáticos não são herdados, então essa classe `Base` sequer parece fazer sentido.

> Isso quer dizer que para cada primeiro método de teste executado em cada classe, terei uma carga na memória da propriedade `driverGC` que nunca será liberada?

Não só existirá um em toda aplicação. Se o seu valor não for explicitamente mudado só existirá um objeto referenciado por ele. Mesmo que mude para um novo objeto, o anterior será descartado tão logo seja possível se não tiver novas referências para ele. Nada precisa ser feito.

> Ou, sendo a propriedade de uma classe que não é estática, ela será removida junto a liberação da classe?

O que importa é a propriedade ser estática. A única coisa que uma classe estática faz é não permitir que existam membros não estáticos, além de, claro não permitir herdar, o que não faria sentido.

> Ou, ainda, esta propriedade virá para a próxima classe com os valores obtidos na execução da classe anterior?

Não entendi o que é isto, mas com toda explicação já dada acho que dá para concluir o que quer saber.

> Isso acarretará em liberação de memória após execução?

Não, leia mais abaixo. E observe o que já escrevi em cima.

> Ah, e como faço pra acompanhar todos os objetos carregados em memória em tempo de execução e suas respectivas liberações? Tem como?

Alguma coisa pode ser pelo próprio *debugger* do Visual Studio ou outro IDE. Outras só com um [*profiler*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/153878/101).

Leituras complementares:

- [Membros estáticos são coletados pelo GC quando não são mais necessários?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/203590/101)
- [Método Dispose()](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/173210/101)
- [Devo sempre utilizar Dispose()?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/22284/101)
- [Quais tipos de recursos são liberados em uma declaração "using"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/163768/101)
- [Quando é recomendável que uma classe implemente IDisposable?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/98341/101)
- [O que significa '~' na frente do construtor de uma classe C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/9078/101)
- [Quando devo usar GC.SuppressFinalize()?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/102609/101)

Comment: A função do Iniciar no contexto é adicionar os modificadores e parametro na execução dos métodos de teste. Certo? Caso contrário eu teria que adicionar a cada método o parametro e o modificador estático, já que são requeridos. Não tem problema utilizar desta metodologia, certo? O caso do Finalizar, sim, sempre passa nesse método quando concluiu os testes dessa classe. Lembrando que implementei ambos em todas as classes. Já que todas as minhas classes tem a propriedade de IWebDriver estática e ela não deve ser herdada, então devo colocar explicitamente na classe, isso?

Comment: O que eu gostaria de evitar seria ter um montão de objetos em memória que já não preciso mais. Fiz o teste removendo o modificador estático da propriedade e ele abre para cada testezinho uma nova instancia do navegador... Então se no método finalizar eu atribuir null a propriedade, o que é que muda, se ela vai estar ali até o final da aplicação de qlqr forma? Tenha paciencia se isso tá chato  mas é pq tá difícil de compreender e aceitar..

Comment: Não sei, tem algo específico no *framework* de teste que exige isto? Esse `context` é usado em algum lugar? Se é pra estar em todas classes deveria estar em `Base`, mas continua valendo o resto que eu disse, não faz sentido em algo estático, e menos ainda usar isso em algo que não tem isso. A impressão que eu tenho é que está tentando fazer várias coisas sem saber porque, isto não dá certo. Me parece que deve ser estático mesmo e não herdá-lo. Na verdade parece ter tantos erros neste código que até é difícil entender o que deseja de fato. Não entendi para que serve a maioria do que está nele.

Comment: Sim, é exigência de que todos os métodos de teste sejam estáticos e tenham como parâmetro este objeto. Mas isso não é o caso. E obrigada a respeito da propriedade estática, vou transferi-la para as classes. Quanto a dúvida efetiva, não menosprezando as demais informações que me passou, se eu passar null pra essa propreidade, vou ter algum ganho? Ou será o mesmo que não fazê-lo?

Comment: Na verdade eu acho que não é o caso de passar para as classes é que não faz sentido ter essa herança. Se quer ter uma única instância do *browser* deve ser estática em uma classe separada que não deve ser herdade, e não ter várias cópias dela. Eu não sei exatamente o contexto, mas está me parecendo que o `null` não será útil, se fizer certo. O problema é que não sei se está certo.

Comment: Alterei o código no post de acordo com suas notas. Sim, na verdade deve ser como você disse. O driver deveria ser passado de outra forma para as classes, pois assim, cada classe de teste executa uma instancia do navegador. Sendo assim, nada de null e vou passar a tratar esse objeto como um objeto estático de acordo com a sua finalidade. Obrigada pela ajuda, @bigown

Comment: Não deveria fazer isto porque descaracterizou a pergunta, então minha resposta agora é sobre algo que não está mais na pergunta. Eu ainda não sei se esta é uma boa solução, porque tudo ainda está estranho.

Comment: Retornei a edição. Então o que está estranho? Vim procurando por ajuda, fique a vontade.

Comment: Não sei, todo o código faz pouco sentido pra mim, eu não sei bem o que deveria fazer.